# Center multiple row list items with specific amount per row

Tags: html, css, list, center, multirow

I'm trying to create an unordered list spanning over multiple rows that is always centered and  where I can set which child breaks into a second row, for example -

```
    link | link | link | link
link | link | link | link | link
```

(where I set the list to clear for a second row on the fifth child element)

Going for an inline display solution to center the elements, I couldn't find a way of clearing them so I switched back to having a float based list. While this easily handles clearing, I find it difficult to center multiple rows -

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
}
li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    right: 50%;
}
li:nth-child(5) {
    clear: left;
}
```

With this style, the list loses center alignment as soon as a second row is made.
Ideas?

Solved using inline approach and nth-child / after pseudo attributes - http://jsfiddle.net/2LULR/

Comment: "where I can set which child breaks into a second row" is not demonstrated in your question. How does this work?

Comment: I think `li:nth-child(5) { clear: left; }` is what the OP means.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I mean that I want to be able to force a break for one of the child elements. Sorry if it sounded confusing.

Comment: I am wondering how you create the | separator, is it a character (pipe symbol) or a border on a link or item element?  Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Or even better: Create a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To center multiple floats rows you have to center them *manually*. So I think the best solution is using `display: inline` and center them by setting the parent element to have a `text-align: center`.

And to *clear* or make a new row, I would do something like this:

```
li:nth-child(5):after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I tried that exact approach on inline elements and it doesn't "clear" the row. But maybe it just needs some tweaking.

Comment: Never mind what I said, it does work! http://jsfiddle.net/2LULR/
Must be my other style settings that interfered with it, or I was  referencing the element wrong (I'm using LESS). Thanks!